# Find an orthonormal basis in 3-D Euclidian space.

Tags: linear-algebra

> To Find:
>   An orthonormal basis in 3-dimensional Euclidian space by applying the Gram-Schmidt process on the basis
>   $$u_1=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 1\\ 
> 1
> \end{bmatrix},u_2=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 3\\ 
> 9
> \end{bmatrix},u_3=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 9\\ 
> 81
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>    now let
>   $$w_1=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 1\\ 
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   $$w_2=u_2-\frac{\left \langle u_2,w_1 \right \rangle}{\left \| w_1 \right \|^2}$$
>   $$=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 3\\ 
> 9
> \end{bmatrix}-\frac{13}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 1\\ 
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
> -10\\ 
> -4\\ 
> 14
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>     $$w_3=u_3-\frac{\left \langle u_3,w_1 \right \rangle}{\left \| w_1 \right \|^2}w_1-\frac{\left \langle u_3,w_2 \right \rangle}{\left \| w_2 \right \|^2}w_2$$
>   $$w_3=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 9\\ 
> 81
> \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{91}{3}\\ 
> \frac{91}{3}\\ 
> \frac{91}{3}
> \end{bmatrix}- \frac{1134-46}{100+16+196}w_2$$
>   But where to from here? I need the ONB but do not have a neat fractional basis - can I ignore the fraction $\frac{91}{3}$ and just put $91$ instead?

Comment: You should be dividing a value and you cannot multiply 2 column vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question:

The [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) defines the projection operator as $p_u(v) = \frac{<v,u>}{||u||^2} u$

So in the second step the formula should be:

$$w_2 = u_2 - p_{w_1}(u_2) = u_2 - \frac{<w_1,u_2>}{||w_1||^2} w_1$$

Rather than $w_2=u_2-\frac{\left \langle u_2,w_1 \right \rangle}{\left \| w_1 \right \|^2}$

For the second question:

When one use the first step of the Gram-Schmidt process(i.e. to get an orthogonal basis),

one then normalize it (i.e. divide it by its norm) so that one gets the orthonormal basis.

During the process, one should not use the orthonormal vector as vector which spanned the line.

Addendum:

It is totally legitimate to write $<u,v>$ as dot product albeit for $u$ and $v$ to be the column vector

because $<u,v> = <I,u^{T}v> = u^{T}v$ where u,v are matries with real entries.

Comment: Should code be:$$w_3=u_3-\frac{\left \langle u_3,w_1 \right \rangle}{\left \| w_1 \right \|^2{w_1}}-\frac{\left \langle u_3,w_2 \right \rangle}{\left \| {w_2} \right \|^2w_2}$$ for third step? I think there should be $w_i$'s in the terms?

Comment: @27182818sheena Yes, you got it.